# How to stop window.scroll() after specific event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap collapse() script to expand/collapse a div. I want to append window.scroll() method on .hidden() and stop the window.scroll() in .shown(). But the window.scroll() always append to that div.

My code snippet

```
    $('body').delegate('#div1', 'shown', function() {
    $('#label').children('i').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
    $('#label').children('i').addClass('icon-minus-sign');
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$('body').delegate('#div1', 'hidden', function() {
    $('#label').children('i').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
    $('#label').children('i').addClass('icon-plus-sign');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#content').stop().animate({
            "marginTop": (scrollTop + '40px;' : (scrollTop) + "px" }, "slow");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').delegate('#div1', 'shown', function () {
    $('#label').children('i').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
    $('#label').children('i').addClass('icon-minus-sign');
    $(window).off('scroll');
});

$('body').delegate('#div1', 'hidden', function () {
    $('#label').children('i').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
    $('#label').children('i').addClass('icon-plus-sign');
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#content').stop().animate({
            "marginTop": (scrollTop + '40px;': (scrollTop) + "px"
            },
            "slow");
        });
    })
```

NOTE: You should use `.on()` instead of `delegate`